# Images not showing in second ios app target

Tags: ios, image, uiimageview

I've got an app, which works plenty good. I've duplicated the target, so I have 2 very similar apps with slightly different functionality - it's not a lite app, but the same kind of principal.

I've copied a lot of the graphics and added them into the project. I can add the images to my .xib files and I see them fine, but when I run my code, using conditional statements to programatically update image views to use the new images, it don't work!
The code runs but what I see in the app is an *empty* image view. So it changes the source of the image view, but doesn't actually show the help.

```
#ifdef OTHER_VERSION
[self.imgTitle setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"differentImage"]];
#endif
```

I know the **#ifdef OTHER_VERSION** code works, because it *is* changing the functionality of my app later on, it's only the images that I'm having a problem with.

Do I need to update the project or something, or add the images specifically to the new target?

**UPDATE:** 
I just noticed this:
    Could not load the "differentImage.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.domain.SecondApp"

The image definitely exists in the project, is the image somehow associated only with the original app I copied from, "com.domain.FirstApp"

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project with Shift-Apple-K? I find that this usually solves missing images in my projects. I'm not sure if you have to do it every time you change versions, though.

Comment: I did try a clean yes, I had the same thought you did but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select your target on the left in Xcode. On the right, click on Build Phases. Expand "Copy Bundle Resources" and ensure all of your images (and other resources) are listed there.

Comment: Woohoo thanks Nathanial, that wasn't mentioned in any of the tutorials I've come across. Cheers!

Comment: My pleasure. Source files can also get excluded/missing from the "Compile Sources" section, frameworks from their section, etc. If you get an error saying that a source file wasn't found, but it's in your project, that's a good place to check.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently had a problem in which an image within an image catalogue was showing up only in one target, but not the other. The image catalogue had both targets selected in its target membership, the catalogue was part of the 'Copy Bundle Resources' for both targets and both images were named correctly.

After some frustration, I found that right clicking the image that was not showing and selecting 'Show in Finder' would show the image and it's related `Contents.json` file. Comparing the two, I noticed the image that wasnt showing was missing multiple `filename:"my_file_name.png"` elements.

Adding the relevant `filename` resolved this:

```
{
  "images" : [
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "my_file_name.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "scale" : "3x"
    }
  ],
  "info" : {
    "version" : 1,
    "author" : "xcode"
  }
}
```